# getting 404 error with codeigniter's controllers on wamp server 64

Tags: php, codeigniter, wampserver

I'm using codeigniter on wampserver, i'm very new to to the model controller views and i'm trying to understand well how it's works.
Currently, i'm trying to do a basic creation of a controller:
In /application/controllers/pages.php i just made this:

```
<?php

    class Pages extends CI_Controller{
    public function one(){
        echo 'hello world';
    }
    }

?>
```

So, yes, this is very basic but i get stuck with an 404 error when i try to reach the method with chrome: http://localhost/test/pages/one/

I've looked on internet several tutorials that were doing the same thing as i do but they get the "hello world" in their web page.

I've found that it might be because i was not typing index.php in my URL but i've modified my config.php and my route.php to no longer have to type it:

config.php:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/test';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Index File
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Typically this will be your index.php file, unless you've renamed it to
| something else. If you are using mod_rewrite to remove the page set this
| variable so that it is blank.
|
*/
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

routes.php:

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'pages/view';
$route['pages'] = 'pages/$1';
$route['(:any)'] = 'pages/view/$1';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
```

What bothers me the most is that when i'm using this codeigniter's example it works well and i don't get the 404 error:

```
class Pages extends CI_Controller{
public function view($page = 'home')
{
        if ( ! file_exists(APPPATH.'views/pages/'.$page.'.php'))
        {
                // Whoops, we don't have a page for that!
                show_404();
        }

        $data['title'] = ucfirst($page); // Capitalize the first letter

        $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('pages/'.$page, $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer', $data);
}
}
```

If i try to create another function it will be totally ignore.
I suppose that i have a problem with my routing files or a problem with codeigniter's installation but in case of, i prefer asking before reinstall all...

Is someone having an answer to my problem? Thanks a lot.

Comment: can you please rename controller file name with `Pages.php` and  use this url `http://localhost/test/Pages/one/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your routes from

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'pages/view';
$route['pages'] = 'pages/$1';
$route['(:any)'] = 'pages/view/$1';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
```

to

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'pages/one';
$route['pages'] = 'pages/$1';
$route['(:any)'] = 'pages/one/$1';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
```

Comment: it worked, i didn't well understood the routing of my files and now i get what i've done wrong, thanks a lot!!